What are the 3.7 and 2.7 in the parentheses in this chart?

What are these numbers (3.6 2.7 and 4.9)
Do they indicate distance?

Yes, that is distance in Nautical Miles for the segment indicated with the arrow. Data is depicted for each with minimum altitude, course, and distance.

And the specification that covers this is section 3.4.4.13, Terminal Routes. https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/iac/media/IAC4/IAC-4-04SEP2024-complete.pdf#page77
